# serious problem with my signed apk Blocked by Play Protect

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, keystore, sign

I get the Blocked by Play Protect message when I want to install my signed .apk file in any Android Devices. 
So I searched a lot about it and we all know the reason (apk is not publishing on Google Play Store) and the solution (Sign apk again or Fill the Play Protect Appeals Submission Form).

I tried to sign my apk many and many times. when I sign the apk again with new keystore it's working for 2 days. after that the message will come again.

but about the play protect appeals form. I can't understand why the google has a problem with my apk file. I filled this form many times with many links on various servers. but immediately after submit I'm getting this message on my inbox.

> Hi
>
> You recently submitted an appeal for an app with Google Play Protect.
>
> The link you have provided does not lead to an APK file or the file is corrupted. Please submit a new appeal and check that you are providing the link to the correct APK file.
>
> Thank You,
>   Google Play Protect Team

So What should I do when Google can't read my apk file and keep saying that it's corrupted while it's working fine?!

Do we have anyone here who had this problem and get solved?

Does this problem happen again in future apps with the same keystore?

It seems a serious problem that Google made for Android developers!

**UPDATE**

Minimum Android Version is:
Android 4.4 (API Level 19 - Kit Kat)

Target Android Version is:
Android 8.1 (API Level 27 - Oreo)

Keystore Details:

> Keystore Path: "C:\Users\farhad\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Keystore\FarhadMa\FarhadMa.keystore"
>   Alias name: FarhadMa
>   Creation date: Dec 25, 2018
>   Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
>   Certificate chain length: 1
>   Certificate[1]:
>   Owner: CN="Farhad Mahmoudvand, OU=Mobile Apps Developer, O=FarhadMa as Freelancer (farhadma.com), L=Tbilisi, S=Tbilisi, C=GE"
>   Issuer: CN="Farhad Mahmoudvand, OU=Mobile Apps Developer, O=FarhadMa as Freelancer (farhadma.com), L=Tbilisi, S=Tbilisi, C=GE"
>   Serial number: 1068ef74
>   Valid from: Tue Dec 25 01:31:53 GET 2018 until: Thu Dec 17 01:31:53 GET 2048
>   Certificate fingerprints:
>        MD5:  82:7A:F5:96:43:09:56:E3:B7:5D:F4:8B:BD:A9:23:DD
>        SHA1: D6:D4:6E:BA:78:8D:6F:A4:7D:C3:C8:2D:44:7F:D7:44:0C:7F:E4:83
>        SHA256: 95:65:9B:20:0C:92:36:3A:88:6D:62:B6:8B:96:8B:A1:C9:F6:95:51:7A:CD:F3:60:86:2F:58:D1:EB:A5:CF:2C
>        Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
>        Version: 3

Comment: give me some project details!

Comment: @G.hakim What kind of details do you need? I think This issue is about apk sign and not related to project codes!

Comment: I mean the targets and everything , and about your signing key

Comment: I've updated the post with some details

Comment: Remove the fingerprint from it otherwise, there might be integrity issues

Comment: did you fix this issue ,can you please share with us what u had do

Comment: @pic Yes my problem has been solved! Actually I think the Google appeals form working while it returns error message! Currently my signature is working for any apk release

Comment: @Farhad thank u for your reply ,i have the same problem as u i have release many APK before but when i generate release APK of my current app i get this message **Play Protect doesn't recognize this app's developer. Apps from unknown developers can sometimes be unsafe.**
i tried all solutions with no results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is just release an signed apk with correct data in sign file, then complete the [google appeals form](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals), and just be patient for 2 weeks even if you get some error message from Google after submitting the form. 
Your apk will works without blocked error and keep that sign file to use it for your next apps

Comment: How did you provide URL for the apk, I provided dropbox url for my app bundle and google saying it cant be downloaded ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I did some research and found this:

Expiry of the debug certificate

The self-signed certificate used to sign your app for debugging has an expiration date of 365 days from its creation date. When the certificate expires, you will get a build error.

To fix this problem, simply delete the **debug.keystore file**. 
The file is stored in the following locations:

```
~/.android/ on OS X and Linux
C:\Documents and Settings\.android\ on Windows XP
C:\Users\.android\ on Windows Vista and Windows 7, 8, and 10
```

The next time you build and run the debug build type, the build tools will regenerate a new keystore and debug key. Note that you must run your app, building alone does not regenerate the keystore and debug key.

It worked for me. The source of my information is the official android developers site: [`https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing`](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

Comment: No one used debug keys for production builds. Neither play store accepts that.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solving with this steps:

First:
generate a signature in android studio with full details.

Second:
release a simple application apk file with same signature, for example your app just show a simple text and size of that never more than 10mb.

Finally:
send your apk file to this address with fill all fields:

[[https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals]](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals)

After few days(for me i waited 1 week) i released my main app with same signature and i never see Blocked by Play Protect for my application.